# Force Kernel Dependencies Not Inlcude Certain Module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, buildroot

I have a kernel module *modA.ko* that depends upon exported symbols.

```c
exported_func1(void)
exported_func2(void)
```

And I have two other modules *modB.ko* and *modC.ko* that has the definitions for exported functions separately. Function signature is the same but functionality is different. Only one of the *modB.ko* or *modC.ko* is supposed to be loaded at the same time. Every time the kbuild determines that *modA.ko* is dependent on *modB.ko*. I don't want that. I want to dynamically load the appropriate modules before using *modA.ko* according to the need.
Is there a way to force the kernel build system to not add dependencies just for this particular module.

I am using Buildroot to build the Linux image but no dependencies are defined in buildroot-config for these modules. In the Buildroot *output/*, both *modB.ko* and *modC.ko* have exported functions listed in the *.symvers* files.

Comment: Would it be possible for modB.ko and modC.ko to depend on a "registration" function exported by modA.ko to set some callback function pointers that implement the functionality of exported_func1 and exported_func2? In other words, is it possible to reverse the direction of the dependency?

Comment: If you cannot reverse the dependencies, you can look-up the values of symbols exported by other loaded modules using the `symbol_get(x)` macro, e.g.: `my_func1_ptr = symbol_get(exported_func1);`. If the symbol is found (`my_func1_ptr` is non-null), the call should be paired with a call to `symbol_put(my_func1_ptr);` when the symbol is no longer required (for example when unloading the module).

Comment: "Every time the kbuild determines that `modA.ko` is dependent on `modB.ko`." - What is a problem in having such dependency from kbuild? You don't want to rebuild `modB.ko` every time you build `modA.ko`? Or what?

Comment: @Tsyvarev The question concerns module load dependencies rather than build dependencies.

Comment: How would depmod know what to put in the modules.symbols (and modules.symbols.bin) file if you have two modules exporting the same symbols?

Comment: I guess, it binds the one it finds first. Qs a workaround, I have disabled ModB.ko in buidroor configuration and MobA is not auto linked to ModC.ko

Comment: @IanAbbott: I asked for elaboration because Kernel build system (**kbuild**) is only responsible for **building** the modules. The phrase "Every time the kbuild determines" is not quite correct: It is `depmod` utility which collects **dependencies** between modules and allows `modprobe` to load these dependencies automatically.

Comment: Answering my own "How would depmod know... ?" question above, I understand this depends on the order the modules are listed in the Makefile (and consequently listed in the "modules.order" file in the module build directory). (See description of modules.order in [Kbuild](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kbuild.html).)